# Specifying source & target cells of a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro which works fine. I've been trying to specify the source cells (rows and columns) and the target cells(rows and columns) in the code but so far I was unsuccessful.

```
Sub mainx()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    With Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
            For Each r In .Cells
                Set c = .Find(r.Value, r, , 1, , , 2)
                If (c.Address <> r.Address) Then   
                    If c.Row > r.Row Then           
                        r.Offset(, 40) = c.Row - r.Row - 1
                    Else
                        Do
                            Set c = .FindNext(c)
                        Loop While c.Row = r.Row And c.Address <> r.Address
                        If c.Row > r.Row Then
                            r.Offset(, 40) = c.Row - r.Row - 1
                        Else
                            r.Offset(, 40) = "na"
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    r.Offset(, 40) = "na"
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The current code generates the results in the second row and after 40th column, and the code works on all the values until 40th column.

I need to make the code work on the data between `A15:N100` (source cells), and output the results in `AO15:BB100` (target cells). So that the values in between won't be affected by the code.

How can I achieve this, please? Can I get a little help? Many thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do with your code?  Your question is not clear.  To set your source and results ranges as you write, you can merely do `Set rSrc = Range("A15:N100")` and similar for the results.

Comment: Thanks, Ron. the code finds out the nearest repeating value in the previous data and outputs the row number. `Set rSrc = Range("A15:N100")` where should I put this exactly, and for the target cell how'd it be? can you give your solution as an answer, please?

Comment: You would replace whatever line you are using to set your source range now, with that line.  And while I may have answered one of your direct questions, it seems this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  If that is the case, I suggest you backup your thinking and redo your question using  [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with VBA, I've tried changing the numbers in the code, to locate the source and target cells, It was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

```
Sub mainx()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range


    With Range("A15:N100")
        For Each r In .Cells
            Set c = .Find(r.Value, r, , 1, , , 2)
            If (c.Address <> r.Address) Then
                If c.Row > r.Row Then
                    r.Offset(, 40) = c.Row - r.Row - 1
                Else
                    Do
                        Set c = .FindNext(c)
                    Loop While c.Row = r.Row And c.Address <> r.Address
                    If c.Row > r.Row Then
                        r.Offset(, 40) = c.Row - r.Row - 1
                    Else
                        r.Offset(, 40) = "na"
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                r.Offset(, 40) = "na"
            End If
        Next
    End With


End
```